# Auto update textfield with DateTime on button Click

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to update a forms textfield with the date and time when a user clicks the button. Cant seem to get it to work.

```
    <form id="form1" action="http://google.com">

<input id="textField1" type="text" value="0" align="right" size="13"/><br>

<input id="button1" type="button" value="1" onclick="display()">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display()
    {
       document.getElementById("textField1").value = "<?php echo datetime() ?>";
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: currently the textfield is updated with the entire php string i.e <?php echo datetime() ?>

Comment: you do realize that php runs on the server, and javascript runs on the client? Do you expect your webserver to be able to magically reach into a browser and change that time value when someone clicks the button? You'll just be inserting the SAME timevalue on every click, because the time value was created ONCE when php was building the page, and then it's just a chunk of text embedded in the page, unchanging.

Comment: [read read read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Date.toString](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) for this

```
function display() {
    var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById("textField1").value = date.toString();
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st9km/)